# Регулярка для математического выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Данные поступают в виде "математический знак(+ или -)" и число (целое или действительное), например:

```
+10, -8.34, +2.00
```

Я составил выражение, которое "пропускает" только действительные числа. Как его дополнить, чтобы оно соответствовало и целым числам?

```
/[\+\-][0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,2}$/
```

UPDATE (через полчаса):
вот так вроде бы работает:

```
/[\+\-][0-9]{1,6}(\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}$/
```

Но как-то криво выглядит...

Comment: как то длинно у вас вышло ... `[+-]\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$` полностью эквивалентно. потому как внутри `[]` экранировать никакие символы, кроме `\` и `]` не надо (минус при этом должен быть первым или последним). `{0,1}` обозначается как `?`. `[0-9]` обозначается как `\d`

Answer (score 1):

Так?

[`/((?:\+|\-)?\d+(?:\.(?=\d+)\d+)?)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/rD4nG7/2)

Comment: Нет, ваше выражение пропускает строку с двумя точками! И вообще буквы тоже пропускает...

Comment: `^([\-\+]?\d{1,3}(?:(?<!\.)\.\d{1,2})?)$`

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/G6lpXY/1

Возможно так будет симпатичнее

`([+-]\d+.{0,1}\d+)[,\s]`

Вход: `+10, -8.34, +2.00, 13, -44.55.1, 66., a.b5, 6e.45, b, 33,., +45.1`

Выход (4 совпадения): `+10, -8.34, +2.00, +45.1`

Еще вариант:

https://regex101.com/r/G6lpXY/2

`((?:[+-]\d+\.\d+)|(?:[+-]\d+))[,\s]`

- Вынимаются две альтернативные группы, разделенный | или
- Первая группа описывает действительные числа +/-, далее цифры, одна точка, далее цифры
- Вторая группа описывает целые числа +/-, далее цифры
- Внутренний группы не вынимаются `(?:<...>)`, вынимается только внешняя, вбирающая в себя обе альтернативные группы
- Верхняя группа должна оканчиваться либо запятой (промежуточные значения), либо пробельным символом - последнее значение